# Can I cluster Accumulo data without using temporary files?

Tags: opencv, mahout, apache-spark, k-means, accumulo

I'd like perform a kmeans clustering on some data that we have in Accumulo. My first thought was to use the kmeans clustering in Apache Mahout, but I'm having a difficult time connecting the two without using temporary files. As near as I can tell, in order to use Mahout, I would need to write the Accumulo data into a series of vector files stored in HDFS, then use Mahout to cluster them, then write the results back into Accumulo (the Mahout entry points all seem to take paths to directories). Although I haven't tried it yet, that just seems like a performance nightmare. Is there a better way? Alternatively, are there other kmeans clustering libraries available that would have an easier time connecting to Accumulo? I'm looking into opencv now, but other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you looked into using Spark and Accumulo?

Comment: I'm looking into it, @user1146334. If I can bridge the gap between `AccumuloInputFormat` and `RDD<Vector>`, I'll be good to go.

Comment: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Accumulo-and-Spark-td13923.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @user1146334, but I think I figured it out today. I should be able to use `JavaSparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD()`followed by a call to `RDD.map()`. If that works out, I'll post an answer. My only problem at this point is dealing with an unexpected feature of our dataset.

Comment: I'd be curious to see your solution as I was thinking of doing something similar myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FuriousGeorge suggested, I looked into Apache Spark. This does indeed provide a way to perform kmeans clustering without using temporary files, as so:

```java
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapreduce.AccumuloInputFormat;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Key;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Value;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.security.Authorizations;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class ClusterAccumuloData
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("yarn-cluster",
                                               "JobName",
                                               "/spark/installation/directory",
                                               "/path/to/jar/file/containing/this/class");
    Configuration conf = new Configuration(); // As near as I can tell, this is all we need.
    Authorizations auths = new Authorizations("whatever_you_need");
    AccumuloInputFormat.setInputInfo(conf,
                                     "accumulo_user",
                                     "users_password".getBytes(),
                                     "accumulo_table_name",
                                     auths);
    AccumuloInputFormat.setZooKeeperInstance(conf, 
                                             "accumulo_instance_name",
                                             "zookeeper_server_1,zookeeper_server_2");
    // Calls to other AccumuloInputFormat functions (such as setRanges or addIterator)
    // that configure it to retrieve the data you wish to cluster.
    JavaPairRDD<Key, Value> accumuloRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf,
                                                             AccumuloInputFormat.class,
                                                             Key.class,
                                                             Value.class);
    JavaRDD<Vector> kmeansDataRDD =
      accumuloRDD.map(new Function<Tuple2<Key, Value>, Vector>()
                      {
                        public Vector call(Tuple2<Key, Value> accumuloData)
                        {
                          // Code which transforms accumuloData into either a
                          // DenseVector or a SparseVector, then returns that Vector.
                        }
                      });
    KMeansModel kmm = KMeans.train(JavaRDD.toRDD(kmeansDataRDD), 42, 14, 37);
  }
}
```